# trying to send data from thingworx composer to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, thingworx

[image: service for data insert][image: subscription for data][image: service for insert data into table[![][1]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le1Vl.jpg)[[image: data from sensor comes here in thing sensordata which uses mqqtt template]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4rEv.png)[image: connection to PostgreSQL]

I created one thing which access my database table name is sensordata from PostgreSQL. Now I have to send data to these table how. How can I do this?

[image]

I did the connection part of thingworx composer and PostgreSQL db on local setup.

I am trying to send sensor data from thingworx to PostgreSQL db but i am not able to sent it

Comment: Put your code here, show what have you tried so far.

Comment: i did only connection part but i didn't get any document how to send data to postgrel database.

Comment: "*how can I send data to the database?*" - use SQL statements

Comment: i want to know how i can write SQL statement because data is coming from sensor received on thingworx using mqtt client

Comment: I wanted to ask what type of service i have to create for connection between them

Answer (score 1):

You must to do two things:

1 Create a service to insert row in postgresql_conn thing;

- Select 'SQL (Command)' as script type.
- Put somthing like this into script area

  ```
  INSERT INTO sensordata 
  (Temperature, Humidity, Vibration) 
  VALUES ([[TemperatureField]], [[HumidityField]], [[VibrationField]]);
  ```

  TemperatureField, HumidityField, VibrationField are input fields of the service.

2  Create  Subscriptions to sensordata thing.

- As event set AnyDataChange;
- Put something like this in the script area:

  ```
  var params = {
      TemperatureField: me.Temperature,
      HumidityField: me.Humidity, 
      VibrationField: me.Vibration
  };


  var result = Things["postgresql_conn"].InsertRecord(params);
  ```

Now when data of sensordata change one row is add to the postgress table.

Sorry for my english

Comment: thanks for reply.i have one more query your given syntax is for char value what will be the syntax for numeric value while inserting into database

Comment: If Temperature is a numeric column of your db you just need to declare TemperatureField as numeric field.
You need also to pass a numeric value in params when you invoke InserRecord service.

Comment: @swd88: i already created table with numeric type and also passing numeric value only ,([[TemperatureField]], [[HumidityField]], [[VibrationField]]) these format is used for passing var char but i want to pass numeric value what should be the format for that

Comment: Unable to Invoke Service insertdata on postgrelsql_conn : ERROR: column "temperature" is of type numeric but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 75 these error is coming while running insert query

Comment: can you post again last screenshot with new service?

Comment: i added some recent screenshot for your reference

Comment: i need to see the Input/output field of this screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/tGRIZ.jpg to check my hypothesis

Comment: how would i check data value is assign to parmeter in subscription

Comment: add  logger.info("function") to Subscription script